# Android, Java, ListView

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that will allow the user select multiple items from a check view list.

After, I transfer those selected items into a new list view in a different activity.

Now here is the problem:

I want to be able to open certain activities based on the selection of the user in the listview....eg. If the user selects dog from the list....... dog activity should open.....if he selects cat.....cat activity should show up.....That's where I need help

Anyone who can help with a sample code....will appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a list view that show item . at first at the adapter in list view then add listener in list view when user click the list view item  this time listener fire and you can get the item name or position by this listen 
and then you can open other activity according to which list is click.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is a ListActivity (by definition extends ListActivity) you can override the onListItemClick method to handle events.

Otherwise you can implement ***AdapterView.onItemClickListener***, then Override the onItemClick method.

The method takes 4 parameters, AdapterView, View, an Int and a long.

**AdapterView parent**: is basically the parent of the ListView.

**View view:** is the view within the adapter that is clicked.

**int position:** indicates the position or index if you prefer of the item selected

**long id:** represents the row id of the item that was clicked.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String listItemClicked = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        switch(listItemClicked){

    case "Dog": Intent intent = new Intent(this, DogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case "Cat": Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much RomanSB......U ended my woes, God bless u, Would u mind if I have your contact if u on What's App

Comment: @Iamranchojr Your welcome, could you mark my answer as correct if it helped. Give me an email, check my profile for my email address.

Comment: @iamranchojr. Please mark my answer as correct, as it has resolved your dilemma.